# How do I print a specific value from the dotted decimal parts of an IP address in C?

Tags: c

I have a block of code which takes input from a user for an IP address and its subnet mask. I would like to print out specific parts of the IP Address, but I'm not able to do so using the code I've written and attached to this thread. Any help would be appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int inputIP(unsigned char a, unsigned char b,unsigned char c,unsigned char d){
      scanf("%hhu.%hhu.%hhu.%hhu", &a,&b,&c,&d);
      printf("%hhu\t%hhu\t%hhu\t%hhu\t\n", a, b, c, d);
}

int main()
{
    unsigned char a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h;
      inputIP(a,b,c,d);
      inputIP(e,f,g,h);
      printf("%hhu",a);
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: First try to write a function which swaps two numbers and call that function from `main` then print the variables,  doing that you will come to know the problem you are facing here.

Comment: The variable `a` in `inputIP` is different from the variable `a` in `main`.

Comment: `a,b,c,d` are not returned from function. You shoud pack them to a structure and return it or pass by reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn pointers.

```
int inputIP(unsigned char *a, unsigned char *b,unsigned char *c,unsigned char *d){

      int result = scanf("%hhu.%hhu.%hhu.%hhu", a,b,c,d);
      printf("%hhu\t%hhu\t%hhu\t%hhu\t\n", *a, *b, *c, *d);
      return result;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned char a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h;
      inputIP(&a,&b,&c,&d);
      inputIP(&e,&f,&g,&h);
      printf("%hhu\n",a);
      return 0;
}
```